# How to finish activity in broadcastreceiver onCallEnded()

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, sip

I have a question, how to finish activity in brodcastreceiver onCallEnded (SIP) . There is a brodcastreceiver like this:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
        try {

            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

                ...

                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {

                 // IncomingCallActivity.finish();

                }
            };

            Main mainActivity = (Main) context;
            incomingCall = mainActivity.manager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);
            mainActivity.call = incomingCall;

            Intent i = new Intent(context, IncomingCallActivity.class);  
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
            context.startActivity(i);
```

Then start new activity to answer or reject call, but how to close it when call is finished? Cant use `IncomingCallActivity.finish()` in `onCallEnded`.

Comment: register the listener in the activity

Comment: hello, have u got answer ?  if u have  than please help me i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {

             // IncomingCallActivity.finish();
             //Here set any value like an int
             intToClose = 1;

            }
```

then in your activity check for the `intToClose`, if its 1 then just call `fnish();`

UPDATE: This code is from my mind, so it can have some errors. Add this to your current activity, or something like this:

```
scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor ( );
                    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate ( new Runnable ( ) {
                public void run ( )
                    {
                      runOnUiThread ( new Runnable ( ) {
                      public void run ( ) {
                      closeInt = IncomingCallReceiver.intToClose;
                      if ( closeInt == 1 ) {    
                          scheduler.shutdown ( );       
                          finish ( );
                       }

                     }
                } );
            }
        }, 750, 750, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
```

Comment: But how to check for intToClose in started activity? When I do it in while(intToClose!=1) { doSmth...} finish() app hangs

Comment: Ok I edited my post with one code to check it (Note that you can do this with many many different things.)

Answer (score 0):

First why can you add the listener in IncomingCallActivity itself. I dont think that will make any difference.

Second for your solution,

start your activity with a FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP so that you receive the new Intent in onNewIntent(Intent intent) of the activity.

Then onCallEnded start the activity once again.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, IncomingCallActivity.class);  
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);  
i.putExtra("Close", true); // an extra which says to finish the activity.
context.startActivity(i);
```

Now in onNewIntent(Intent intent)

```
if(intent.getBooleanExtra("Close", false))
  finish();
```

Comment: But I cant use variable context in method onCallEnded(). getApplicationContext() doesn't work too

Comment: You can use the context variable after setting that to final in onCallEnded(). since its an inner class you can access all the variables in onReceive.

Answer (score 0):

- I used this code my problem solved.
- Try this your problem will be solve. there is no `endcall` in broadcast so `finish()` on Idle state.
  Happy coding!!

  ```
  if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
     ((Activity)context).finish();
  }
  ```