# NullPointerException while starting new Activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver, android-activity

My last topic: [How to finish activity in broadcastreceiver onCallEnded()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140021/how-to-finish-activity-in-broadcastreceiver-oncallended)

Tried to move listener to `IncomingCallActivity` , so edited `IcomingCallReceiver` to:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, IncomingCallActivity.class);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
        context.startActivity(i); 
   }
```

Now getting `NullPointerExeption` when starting new Activity... Any ideas why?

**LOGCAT**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at IncomingCallActivity.onCreate(IncomingCallActivity.java:34)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>           ... 11 more

With this code:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
     try {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
            ...

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {

             // IncomingCallActivity.finish();

            }
        };

        Main mainActivity = (Main) context;
        incomingCall = mainActivity.manager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);
        mainActivity.call = incomingCall;

        Intent i = new Intent(context, IncomingCallActivity.class);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
        context.startActivity(i);
```

activity stared without troubles, but i need to move listener to `IncomingCallActivity`

Comment: can you please update the logcat error message which you are getting.

Comment: post your IncomingCallActivity Activity code also

Comment: there are problem in IncomingCallActivity.java on line 34 - show it

Comment: its:  String contactName = Main.call.getPeerProfile().getDisplayName();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at IncomingCallActivity.onCreate(IncomingCallActivity.java:34)
```

Look at 34 line in IncomingCallActivity in onCreate() method.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Look Here:

Check line no 34 in IncomingCallActivity activity and paste IncomingCallActivity activity code.